# python enum.Enum _value_ vs value

Tags: python, enums

```
from enum import Enum
class Type(Enum):
  a = 1
  b = 2

print Type.a.value, Type.a._value_
```

This prints

```
1 1
```

What is the difference between _ value_ and value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `.value` is the `property`-backed version and cannot be changed:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class Color(Enum):
...   red = 1
...   green = 2
...   blue = 3
... 
>>> Color.green
<Color.green: 2>
>>> Color.green.value
2
>>> Color(2)
<Color.green: 2>
>>> Color.green.value = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/types.py", line 141, in __set__
    raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

But `._value_` is where the actual value is stored in the instance-dict, and can be changed:

```
>>> Color.green._value_ = 4
>>> Color.green
<Color.green: 4>
```

As [Tobias explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48524795/208880), names that begin with an underscore should be avoided unless you have a really good reason, as you can break things using them:

```
>>> Color(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/enum.py", line 241, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/enum.py", line 476, in __new__
    raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
ValueError: 4 is not a valid Color
```

Answer (score 4):

The docs are a bit unclear, but as I understand the docs, `_value_` is only to be used to set the value if you write your own `__new__` constructor. This will later result in `value` being set by the metaclass provided by the `enum` module.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#supported-sunder-names

Per convention, names starting with an underscore are "private" members of a class so definitely go with `.value`.